# Recommendations are coming same before and after fit_partial for new interactions for any user lightfm

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, personalization, lightfm

for any user let's say some new interactions come then I am fitting the dataset and model with only new interactions data using partial_fit and I am getting the same results before and after partial fit for that user.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand the program but I think you are not getting the dessired results because you are not defining functions and hence you are working with global variables instead of local ones

try:

```
def makeitems(df2,user):
     ...
     return itemfeatures
```

I wanted to comment but I need 50 rep